# Catch Double Click event on react leaflet polygon (circle)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet

I can catch the single click event

```
<Circle onClick={ (event) => this.seatClickHandler(event, seat) } ... />
```

But I want to catch also double-click event, is that is possible in `react-leaflet`

I had disabled `zoom-in` map on double click, so if there is an event for the map, then should be something available for polygons?

Comment: with rxjs there is a pretty simple solution for that, but i dont know if you want to use rxjs ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to walk around some DOM's limitations.

I used to check if some element is clicked twice in some short period

```
/**
 * Number of clicks.
 * 
 * @type {Number}
 */
let seatClickNumber;

/**
 * Id of element
 * 
 * @type {Number}
 */
let clickedSeatId;

/**
 * Last timeout ID
 * 
 * @type {Number}
 */
let timeoutId;

/**
 * Checks if seat is double clicked.
 * 
 * @param {Object} seat
 * 
 * @returns {boolean}
 */
isDoubleClick = (seat) => {
   if (clickedSeatId === seat['seatLabelId']) {
        seatClickNumber = seatClickNumber + 1;
    }

    clickedSeatId = seat['seatLabelId'];

    clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        clickedSeatId = '';
        seatClickNumber = 1;
    }, 600);

    return seatClickNumber > 1;
};

/**
 * Selects one seat by click event or multiple by holding ctrl key whn clicking.
 *
 * @param {Object} event
 * @param {Object} seat
 */
seatClickHandler = (event, seat) =>
{
    if(this.isDoubleClick(seat)) {
        alert('Double Click!!!');
    }

    let index = this.props.selectedSeats.indexOf(seat);

    if (index !== -1) {
        this.props.deselectSeat(seat);
    } else {
        event.originalEvent.ctrlKey ? this.props.addSelectedSeats(seat) : this.props.setSelectedSeats(seat);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

rxJS based solution use it in contructor or init function:

```
const clickEvents = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document.getElementById('yourId'), 'click');

const unsubscribe$= Rx.Subject()


clickEvents
  .buffer(clickEvents.debounce(300))
  .map(list => list.length)
  .filter(x => x === 2)
  .takeUntil(unsubscribe$)
  .subscribe(() => {
      console.log('you can handle the double click here');
  })
```

whenever you want to kill the subscription to the event

you call a function that uses

```
 unsubscribe$.next()
 unsubscribe$.complete()
```

Comment: I am using React and there are no many options for using another library in project :/

Comment: I had also found some solution without importing external lib, you can check my answer if you want

Answer (score 0):

Don't register click and dblclick events on the same element: it's impossible to distinguish single-click events from click events that lead to a dblclick event.

This is not a limitation of React, it is a limitation of the DOM's click and dblclick events. As suggested by Quirksmode's [click documentation:](https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/click.html)

Comment: I had to do some walk around, you can check my solution.